# How to fill up missing elements in a table?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split

My table:

```
New York  3       books        1000
London    2,25                 2000
Paris     1.000   apples       3000
          30                   4000
Berlin            newspapers
```

I would like to keep the empty fields in the table, fill them up with `xxxx` values and put the entire table in a list.

```
New York  3       books        1000
London    2,25    xxxx         2000
Paris     1.000   apples       3000
xxxx      30      xxxx         4000
Berlin    xxxx    newspapers   xxxx
```

What I've did is to pick up every line and split them.

```
finallist = []
for line in range(1,6):
   listtemp = re.split("\s{2,}", line)
   finallist .append(listtemp)
```

Then I zipped the list

```
zippedlist = zip(*finallist)
```

Checked if the length of columns (now rows) have enough elements and added missing elements `xxxx` add the end, but this doesn't work because it will compact the column (The line split doesn't pick up the empty spaces within a column)

How can I fill up the table with `xxxx` elements and put them in a list like this:

```
[['New York','3','books','1000'],['London','2,25','xxxx','2000'],['Paris','1.000','apples','3000'],['xxxx','30','xxxx','4000'],['Berlin','xxxx','newspapers','xxxx']]
```

another table could be:

```
New York      3         books   1000  
  London      2,25              2000  
   Paris  1.000                 3000  
             30                 4000  
  Berlin  apples    newspapers
```

### **Update**

Both answers did not gave a solution, but I used both to find a different solution (after a lot of trying and trying....)

```
#list of all lines
r = ['New York      3         books   1000  ', '  London      2,25              2000  ', '   Paris  1.000                 3000  ', '             30                 4000  ', '  Berlin  apples    newspapers ']

#split list
separator = "\s{2,}"
mylist = []
for i in range(0,len(r)):
   mylisttemp = re.split(separator, r[i].strip())
   mylist.append(mylisttemp)

#search for column matches
p = regex.compile("^(?<=\s*)\S|(?<=\s{2,})\S") 

i = []
for n in range(0,len(r)):
   itemp = []
   for m in p.finditer(r[n]):
      itemp.append(m.start())
   i.append(itemp)

#find out which matches are on next lines comparing the column match with all the matches of first line (the one with the smallest difference is the match). 
i_currentcols = []
i_0_indexes = list(range(0,len(i[0])))
for n in range(1,len(mylist)):
   if len(i[n]) == len(i[0]):
      continue
   else:
      i_new = []
      for b in range(0,len(i[n])):
         difference = []
         for c in range(0,len(i[0])): #first line is always correct
             difference.append(abs(i[0][c]-i[n][b]))
         i_new.append(difference.index(min(difference)))
      i_notinside = sorted([elem for elem in i_0_indexes if elem not in i_new ], key=int)
      #add linenr.
      i_notinside.insert(0, str(n))
      i_currentcols.append(i_notinside)

#insert missing fields in list
for n in range(0,len(i_currentcols)):
    for i in range(1,len(i_currentcols[n])):
       mylist[int(i_currentcols[n][0])].insert(i_currentcols[n][i], "xxxx")
```

Comment: is your table a text file you build? can you guarantee that the column length does not change? can you split the lines by tab?

Comment: @Francesco, yes it is in a text file. The column length is not always the same, it does change. The nr. of columns and rows are variable as well. No I can't split the lines by tab.

Comment: can you assume that columns are separated by at least two consecutive spaces?

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite challenging but I came up with a solution in two steps:

## Step 1: detect column start positions

The complexity here is that in some lines the column is empty.

The approach is: every double space followed by a not space character identifies a new column start. 0 is always a column start. Search every column start in every line:

```
t = """New York  3       books        1000
London    2,25                 2000
Paris     1.000   apples       3000
          30                   4000
Berlin            newspapers """

p = re.compile("  [^ ]")

i = set([0])
for line in t.split('\n'):
    for m in p.finditer(line):
        i.add(m.start()+2)
i = sorted(i)
```

output: [0, 10, 18, 31]

## Step 2: tokenize every line on those positions

```
def split_line_by_indexes( indexes, line ):
    tokens=[]
    indexes = indexes + [len(line)]
    for i1,i2 in zip(indexes[:-1], indexes[1:]): #pairs
        tokens.append( line[i1:i2].rstrip() )
    return tokens

for line in t.split('\n'):
    print split_line_by_indexes(i, line)
```

output:

```
['New York', '3', 'books', '1000']
['London', '2,25', '', '2000']
['Paris', '1.000', 'apples', '3000']
['', '30', '', '4000']
['Berlin', '', 'newspapers', '']
```

Of course instead of printing you can replace empty values with `xxxx` and write it back to a file

Comment: Grazie. Faccio un test. Giusto per la precisione: "columns are separated by at least two consecutive spaces" At least 2 spaces (not always 2 spaces).

Comment: it does work in above example but not with this example;

Comment: it does work in above example but not with the example I just added at the end of my question. (I was not enable to show it to you in this comment)

Comment: The first line is always correct. The lines below can have even 2 or 3 consecutives empty.

Comment: @Reman The second example you posted is exremely complicated. not only because every column is aligned to the right, but for the second column which is aligned to the comma. I have a solution in my mind but is extremely complicated and i think that you need more assumpions on your input to have a simpler solution

Comment: Your answer and the answer of CPanda did me find a different solution. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very interesting question. I came up with the following succinct code. **It's basically 3 lines**. Given

```
s = """New York      3         books   1000  
       London      2,25                2000  
         Paris     1.000                 3000  
                  30                   4000  
       Berlin  apples    newspapers"""

reg = r'^([\w\s]*?)\s+([\d.,]*?)\s+([\w]*?)\s+([\d]*?)$'
pat = re.compile(reg)
lines = s.splitlines()
# lines could be an `open()` file object
g = (pat.search(line).groups() for line in lines)
result = ([i if i else "xxx" for i in t] for t in g)
# consume the result generator
In [197]: list(result)
Out[197]:
[['New York', '3', 'books', '1000'],
 ['London', '2,25', 'xxx', '2000'],
 ['Paris', '1.000', 'apples', '3000'],
 ['xxx', '30', 'xxx', '4000'],
 ['Berlin', 'xxx', 'newspapers', 'xxx']]
```

See if it works for you. If it does please comment, so that I can go ahead and tell you how to make it *robust* and *efficient*.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work if you consider the comment *"The nr. of columns and rows are variable as well. "*

Comment: @Francesco It's not supposed to. That's why I left the my response open ended(see the last line). The `+/*` in reg can be replaced by `{m,n}` if such information is known and this will account for efficiency. But we are talking about robustness. The char set `[]` in each group should be changed to include appropriate chars. In a way it's a schema. So if there are variable but *determinate* number of cols it can be made to work by adding all the possible groups in reg. If the number is *indeterminate* I don't have a solution right now.

Comment: @CPanda, thanks for your answer. The 2nd column are not always digits. Your answer and the answer of Francesco helped me to find a different solution. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Reman See, the more specific you can be with you regex better the performance, if a certain group has arbitrary chars, you can always use `.*?`

Comment: @CPanda, agree, this is not a bad solution but with my current solution I don't need to adapt the splitter. The splitter is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution which is simple to understand and more generic than my previous answer.

## Step 1: find where to slice

I search for positions that are `space` in every line

```
t = """New York  3       books        1000
London    2,25                 2000
Paris     1.000   apples       3000
          30                   4000
Berlin            newspapers """

p = re.compile(" ")

i = None
for line in t.split('\n'):
    thisline = set()
    for m in p.finditer(line):
        thisline.add(m.start()+2)
    print sorted(thisline)
    if not i:
        i = thisline
    else:
        i.intersection_update(thisline)
i = sorted(i)
```

Then I elaborate the indexes to squash consequent indexes into the same index so that `[10, 11, 17, 18, 19, 30, 31, 32]` becomes `[10, 17, 30]`

```
res = []
last = None
for el in i:
    if not last or el != last + 1:
        res.append(el)
    last = el
```

## Step 2: tokenize every line on those positions

Same as before

```
def split_line_by_indexes( indexes, line ):
    tokens=[]
    indexes = indexes + [len(line)]
    for i1,i2 in zip(indexes[:-1], indexes[1:]): #pairs
        tokens.append( line[i1:i2].rstrip() )
    return tokens

for line in t.split('\n'):
    print split_line_by_indexes(i, line)
```

## Conclusion

This is not perfect nor complete. You need to trim the results and you definitely can optimize the code.

I also saw that you found your solution, but I really wanted to post this since I think it's worth a try